# Creating table view cell containing data from multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am currently trying to create a table view that holds the data across multiple views. The idea is that when you tap the "Create Profile" button it creates the prototype cell containing the data from all the screens. So far I have the UserDefaults saving, the basic table view code, and the prototype cell done. I am not sure how to actually go about accessing all the saved data, and saving it into the cell when the save button is pressed. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code so far.

Picture of view flow: https://gyazo.com/7632601da0c44b61075cafdcc019ba64

First screen with table view:

```
import UIKit

class Billing: UIViewController {

    var profiles = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
    @IBAction func plusAddTaskButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return profiles.count
       }
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell", for: indexPath)
           myCell.textLabel?.text = profiles[indexPath.row]
           return myCell
       }
}
fileprivate func delegates() {
        billingTextView.delegate = self
        FirstName.delegate = self
        LastName.delegate = self
        Email.delegate = self
        Country.delegate = self
        State.delegate = self
        Address.delegate = self
        Address2.delegate = self
        City.delegate = self
        PostalCode.delegate = self
        PhoneNumber.delegate = self
    }
```

Delivery Details Screen:

```
  import Foundation
import UIKit

var billingText: String!
var firstName: String!
var lastName: String!
var email: String!
var phoneNumber: String!
var address: String!
var address2: String!
var city: String!
var postalCode: String!
var country: String!
var state: String!

class AddBilling: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var billingTextView: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Address: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Address2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var City: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PostalCode: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Country: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var State: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var proceedButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var proceedToSecondBillingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondBillingSwitch: UISwitch!



    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        delegates()



        billingTextView.text = defaults.string(forKey: "profileName")
        FirstName.text = defaults.string(forKey: "firstName")
        LastName.text = defaults.string(forKey: "lastName")
        Email.text = defaults.string(forKey: "email")
        PhoneNumber.text = defaults.string(forKey: "phoneNumber")
        Address.text = defaults.string(forKey: "address")
        Address2.text = defaults.string(forKey: "address2")
        City.text = defaults.string(forKey: "city")
        PostalCode.text = defaults.string(forKey: "postalCode")
        Country.text = defaults.string(forKey: "country")
        State.text = defaults.string(forKey: "state")

    }
    fileprivate func secondBillingSwitchState() {
        if (defaults.object(forKey: "secondBillingSwitch") != nil) {
            secondBillingSwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "secondBillingSwitch")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func secondBillingSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if secondBillingSwitch.isOn {
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "secondBillingSwitch")
        } else {
            defaults.set(false, forKey: "secondBillingSwitch")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "profileName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "firstName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "lastName")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "phoneNumber")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "address")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "address2")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "city")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "postalCode")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "country")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "state")

        billingTextView.text = ""
        FirstName.text = ""
        LastName.text = ""
        Email.text = ""
        PhoneNumber.text = ""
        Address.text = ""
        Address2.text = ""
        City.text = ""
        PostalCode.text = ""
        Country.text = ""
        State.text = ""

    }

    @IBAction func proceedToPaymentSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

        billingText = billingTextView.text!
        firstName = FirstName.text!
        lastName = LastName.text!
        email = Email.text!
        phoneNumber = PhoneNumber.text!
        address = Address.text!
        address2 = Address2.text!
        city = City.text!
        postalCode = PostalCode.text!
        country = Country.text!
        state = State.text!

        defaults.set(billingText, forKey: "profileName")
        defaults.set(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        defaults.set(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        defaults.set(email, forKey: "email")
        defaults.set(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        defaults.set(address, forKey: "address")
        defaults.set(address2, forKey: "address2")
        defaults.set(city, forKey: "city")
        defaults.set(postalCode, forKey: "postalCode")
        defaults.set(country, forKey: "country")
        defaults.set(state, forKey: "state")


    }

    fileprivate func delegates() {
        billingTextView.delegate = self
        FirstName.delegate = self
        LastName.delegate = self
        Email.delegate = self
        Country.delegate = self
        State.delegate = self
        Address.delegate = self
        Address2.delegate = self
        City.delegate = self
        PostalCode.delegate = self
        PhoneNumber.delegate = self
    }


}
```

Billing Details Screen:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var firstNameBilling: String!
var lastNameBilling: String!
var addressBilling: String!
var address2Billing: String!
var cityBilling: String!
var postalCodeBilling: String!
var countryBilling: String!
var stateBilling: String!

class AddBilling2: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var FirstNameBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastNameBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AddressBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AddressBilling2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CityBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CountryBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var StateBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PostalCodeBilling: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var proceedButton: UIButton!


    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        delegates()

        FirstNameBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "firstNameBilling")
        LastNameBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "lastNameBilling")
        AddressBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "addressBilling")
        AddressBilling2.text = defaults.string(forKey: "address2Billing")
        CityBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "cityBilling")
        PostalCodeBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "postalCodeBilling")
        CountryBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "countryBilling")
        StateBilling.text = defaults.string(forKey: "stateBilling")
    }
    @IBAction func proceedToPayment(_ sender: UIButton) {

        firstNameBilling = FirstNameBilling.text!
        lastNameBilling = LastNameBilling.text!
        addressBilling = AddressBilling.text!
        address2Billing = AddressBilling2.text!
        cityBilling = CityBilling.text!
        postalCodeBilling = PostalCodeBilling.text!
        countryBilling = CountryBilling.text!
        stateBilling = StateBilling.text!


        defaults.set(firstNameBilling, forKey: "firstNameBilling")
        defaults.set(lastNameBilling, forKey: "lastNameBilling")
        defaults.set(addressBilling, forKey: "addressBilling")
        defaults.set(address2Billing, forKey: "address2Billing")
        defaults.set(cityBilling, forKey: "cityBilling")
        defaults.set(postalCodeBilling, forKey: "postalCodeBilling")
        defaults.set(countryBilling, forKey: "countryBilling")
        defaults.set(stateBilling, forKey: "stateBilling")
    }
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "firstNameBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "lastNameBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "addressBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "address2Billing")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "cityBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "postalCodeBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "countryBilling")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "stateBilling")

        FirstNameBilling.text = ""
        LastNameBilling.text = ""
        AddressBilling.text = ""
        AddressBilling2.text = ""
        CityBilling.text = ""
        PostalCodeBilling.text = ""
        CountryBilling.text = ""
        StateBilling.text = ""
    }
    fileprivate func delegates() {
        FirstNameBilling.delegate = self
        LastNameBilling.delegate = self
        CountryBilling.delegate = self
        StateBilling.delegate = self
        AddressBilling.delegate = self
        AddressBilling2.delegate = self
        CityBilling.delegate = self
        PostalCodeBilling.delegate = self
    }

}
```

Payment Details Screen:

```
import UIKit

var cardHolder: String!
var cardNumber: String!
var expirationDate: String!
var cvc: String!

class AddCreditCard: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var CardName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CardNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CardExpirationDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CardCVC: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createProfileButton: UIButton!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        delegate()

        CardName.text = defaults.string(forKey: "cardHolder")
        CardNumber.text = defaults.string(forKey: "cardNumber")
        CardExpirationDate.text = defaults.string(forKey: "expirationDate")
        CardCVC.text = defaults.string(forKey: "cvc")
    }
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "cardHolder")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "cardNumber")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "expirationDate")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "cvc")

        CardName.text = ""
        CardNumber.text = ""
        CardExpirationDate.text = ""
        CardCVC.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func createProfileButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        cardHolder = CardName.text!
        cardNumber = CardNumber.text!
        expirationDate = CardExpirationDate.text!
        cvc = CardCVC.text!

        defaults.set(cardHolder, forKey: "cardHolder")
        defaults.set(CardNumber, forKey: "cardNumber")
        defaults.set(expirationDate, forKey: "expirationDate")
        defaults.set(cvc, forKey: "cvc")


    }

    fileprivate func delegate() {
        CardName.delegate = self
        CardExpirationDate.delegate = self
    } 
}
```